# How to Load all the Objects in an Array List

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to load through an Array List of Objects. I am able to retrieve the last Object in the Array, but it will not let me Load any other Object after that. here is part of the code I have. As you can see it saves the object to the List, but when I click the loadLastBtn it will only load the most recent entry and if I hit it again after that nothing loads.

```
    List<Members> lstMembers = new List<Members>();
    private int hold;
    private void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstNameTxt.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastNameTxt.Text)
           || string.IsNullOrEmpty(userNameTxt.Text) ||
           string.IsNullOrEmpty(passwordTxt.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(confPassTxt.Text)
           || string.IsNullOrEmpty(majorBox.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(specialtyBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter in all fields before moving forward");
        }
        else
        {
            Members m1 = new Members(firstNameTxt.Text, lastNameTxt.Text, userNameTxt.Text,
                                        passwordTxt.Text, confPassTxt.Text, majorBox.Text,
                                        specialtyBox.Text);
            lstMembers.Add(m1);
        }
    }


   private void loadLastBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstNameTxt.Text = lstMembers[hold].FirstName;
        lastNameTxt.Text = lstMembers[hold].LastName;
        userNameTxt.Text = lstMembers[hold].UserName;
        passwordTxt.Text = lstMembers[hold].Password;
        confPassTxt.Text = lstMembers[hold].ConfPassword;
        majorBox.Text = lstMembers[hold].Major;
        specialtyBox.Text = lstMembers[hold].Specialty;

        hold++;
    }
```

I have edited my answer. this will now print each user one by one each time I hit loadLastBtn, but it does show them from the first user to the last, where I need it to shower the last user to the first.

Comment: It's not only loading the last one. Each time it loops through the array it changes the `Text` property of each textbox and all you see is what was retrieved on the last iteration..

Comment: How do I get it to Load through the array. So every time I hit the loadLastBtn it will load the last textbox Text that I entered until it gets to the first textbox Text user that I enter. right now it is only loading the last iteration and every time I hit the load last button it wont load through anymore objects in the array. @kyriacos_k

Comment: It is (eventually) loading the last one, I'm not sure what it is you want exactly. Do you want it to iterate through the array one by one each time you click the load button?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I want it to do. I need it to iterate through the array one by one every time I hit the load button.. @kyriacos_k

Comment: Well, right now you're iterating through the array using an indexer `i`, right? Here's a hint: instead of looping through the array on each click, you could use a `static` variable to hold the 'current' item and use that to access an item on each click. I suggest you give it a try on your own. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I tried it with an int and it gave me back number values, which is what I was expecting, but I cannot think of anyway as to how to do this. if there is anyway you can show me a hint or something, because i am very lost right now. @kyriacos_k

Comment: never mind. i got it :). thank you. i will post the code above. @kyriacos_k let me know if it looks correct.

Comment: I just added the code @kyriacos_k

Comment: Well done, you're on the right path. You can get rid of the loop, it's redundant. You also need a check to reset the value of hold to 0 once It's equal to the number of items in your collection, so you don't get an ArrayOutOfBounds exception thrown.

Comment: it is showing the first one I enter all the way through to the last one I entered. how do I reverse this? the for iteration was an accident. I also added a catch/throw for it. but I do need help figuring out how to print from the most recent to the latter? @kyriacos_k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is something like this:

```
// -1 Indicates that you should start at the end of the list
int index = -1; 

private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (members != null && members.Count > 0) // Avoid accessing if list is empty or null
    {
        if (index == -1)
            index = members.Count - 1;

        firstNameTxt.Text = lstMembers[index].FirstName;
        lastNameTxt.Text = lstMembers[index].LastName;
        userNameTxt.Text = lstMembers[index].UserName;
        passwordTxt.Text = lstMembers[index].Password;
        confPassTxt.Text = lstMembers[index].ConfPassword;
        majorBox.Text = lstMembers[index].Major;
        specialtyBox.Text = lstMembers[index].Specialty;

        if (index == 0) // Reached beginning of array
            index = -1; // Indicate that next time the last element must be accessed
        else
            --index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int hold = lstMembers.Count -1;
private void loadLastBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    firstNameTxt.Text = lstMembers[hold].FirstName;
    lastNameTxt.Text = lstMembers[hold].LastName;
    userNameTxt.Text = lstMembers[hold].UserName;
    passwordTxt.Text = lstMembers[hold].Password;
    confPassTxt.Text = lstMembers[hold].ConfPassword;
    majorBox.Text = lstMembers[hold].Major;
    specialtyBox.Text = lstMembers[hold].Specialty;

    hold--;
}
```

Comment: I just wrote a comment below it. thank you @KevinBrown. do you by chance know how I get it to show the user objects from the last entered to the first?

Comment: declare hold as hold = lstMembers.Count -1. And instead of "hold++" use "hold --"

Comment: Did that satisfy your question?